# pandas to_datetime leaves unconverted data

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to convert a column with strings that looks like "201905011" (year/month/day) to datetime, ideally showing as 05-01-2019 (month/day/year). I'm currently trying to following but it's not working for me.

```
pd.to_datetime(data.datetime, format = '%Y%m%d%H')
```

This leaves me with the error: "ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4"

I would like to know instead how to correctly do this.

Comment: what is `date.datetime` I thought you had a string? anyway `pd.to_datetime('201905011',format='%Y%m%d%H')` works for me;`Timestamp('2019-05-01 01:00:00')`

Comment: Can you post more data, this works for me

Comment: Look at: `data.loc[pd.to_datetime(data.datetime, format='%Y%m%d%H', errors='coerce').isnull(), 'datetime']`.  This will show you the values that cannot be converted to datetime as they don't match that format. You'll probably see those dates have too many numbers or some other issue.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm trying to do this for a whole column with dates like the string I wrote, edited it now. How does this change things?

Comment: I used ALollz code to find out where the problems were, and at every 24th value it has issues. Is this because my data uses "24" for a time of 00:00 instead of "0"?

Comment: I changed all these "24" values to "0" and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I created an example based on ALollz comment. I have created a dataframe in which first row is correct and second row has and extra 0 in the end. If you use the method, it will return the rows in which the data doesn't match the specified format.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"datefield":["201901010","20190101010"]})
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.datefield, format='%Y%m%d%H', errors='coerce').isnull(), 'datefield']
```

```
1    20190101010
Name: datefield, dtype: object
```